# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in 'XLSX.read()'

Tags: fetch, xlsx

I am using XLSX npm module and getting this error. I am also using fetch and retrieving the xlsx file and returning the buffer. I think I could be doing something wrong in that instance, but not for sure. Here is the code below.

```
const fetchSheet = async () => {
  await connectToDatabase();
  const storedData = await Sheet.find({});
  if (storedData.length > 0) {
    const storedSheet = storedData[0];
    if (storedSheet.status === 'completed' && storedSheet.url !== null) {
      const xlsxFile = await fetch(storedSheet.url).then(res => res.buffer());
      sheetToJSON(xlsxFile);
    }
  }
};

const sheetToJSON = async xlsxFile => {
  const workbook = XLSX.read(xlsxFile, { type: 'buffer' }); // --> THIS IS THROWING THE ERROR
  console.log(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets['Sheet1']));
  const sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
  sheet_name_list.forEach(y => {
    const sheet = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[y]);
    sheet.map(async item => {
      await fs.outputJson(
        path.resolve(__dirname, `../dist/JSON/${item['Item Number']}.json`),
        item
      );
    });
  });
};
```

ERROR: `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`